# Chinese Remainder Theorem with unknown moduli

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We are counting intervals of prime width that can be covered by a set of primes. (By covered we mean every element is a multiple of one of primes.)

Formally,
Let $p_1, \dots p_n$ be the first $n$ prime numbers and $A=(m_1, \dots, m_{p_{n+1}-1})$ be any arrangement of them, including repetition. [Note $|A| = p_{n+1}-1$]

Is there a solution to the system

\begin{align*}
x &\equiv  -1 \pmod  {m_1 }\\
x &\equiv  -2 \pmod {m_2}\\
\vdots \\
x &\equiv  -(p_{n+1}-1) \pmod {m_{p_{n+1}-1}}\\
\end{align*}

For example, if we consider the set of primes $(2,3,5,7,11)$
then there are four solutions to the system. One is given by
\begin{align*}
x &\equiv  -1 \pmod  {5 }\\
x &\equiv  -2 \pmod {2}\\
x &\equiv  -3 \pmod {3}\\
x &\equiv  -4 \pmod {2}\\
x &\equiv  -5 \pmod {7}\\
x &\equiv  -6 \pmod {2}\\
x &\equiv  -7 \pmod {11}\\
x &\equiv  -8 \pmod {2}\\
x &\equiv  -9 \pmod {3}\\
x &\equiv  -10 \pmod {2}\\
x &\equiv  -11 \pmod {5}\\
x &\equiv  -12 \pmod {2}\\
\end{align*}

This has solution $x = 168$. Also, if we swap the 7 and 11 above we get $x = 1608$. Each solution corresponds to a different arrangement of the moduli that 'cover' the interval. Once covered the Chinees Remainder Theorem guarantees a solution.

Anyone know of a way to count the number of solutions in the general case?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this is not an answer to the question as intended, but I am still not too clear what that question is. When we finish our discussion, I will delete this answer. (and hopefully write another one? ^.^)

---

The Chinese remainder theorem does not merely give a solution, it proves the uniqueness of that solution, modulo the gcd of the moduli. So whenever the CRT applies, the answer is $1$.

Also worth noting that the CRT is a very general result, and since everything in sight is coprime, the only reason that it does not apply automatically is because it demands only one equation for each modulus. But note that if you have two equations $x \equiv A_1$ and $x\equiv A_2$ with the same modulus, then either they are redundant or inconsistent. Of course if there are ever two inconsistent equations then the number of solutions is zero. If conversely there are no inconsistent equations, then we can eliminate all the redundancies and condense to a system which has only one equation for each modulus.

The only subtlety is that in your setup you allow redundancy, but do not demand "covering". Assuming that was an intended feature of the problem, the CRT still gives you one solution, but only modulo $\gcd(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_{p_{n+1}-1})$; i.e. the product of all the primes that appear at least once. Thus we need only to count the number of [disjoint] intervals of that size that fit into an interval of size $p_1\times\cdots\times p_n$. In other words, the number of solutions is
$$\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if any two equations are inconsistent,} \\
p_1\times\cdots\times p_n\times \displaystyle\prod_{p=m_k \text{ for at least one }k} \frac{1}{p} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. However it does not answer the question. It is understood that the CRT gives a unique solution, however different arrangements give different unique solutions (see my example).  Another example: Consider the primes $\{ 2,3,5,7,11,13\}$ and a system  $x = - j$ (mod $m_i)$, $j = 1,2,\dots, 16$. There are 28 arrangements of the moduli which give a consistent system, all others fail.

Comment: @CarlOlimb: So if I understand correctly, you are using the word "solution" in two different ways in the OP, and I mixed them up. For a given arrangement, the system may or may not have a solution. And the goal is to count the arrangements that do, correct?

Comment: Okay, after thinking about this I am pretty sure I'm still missing something, because if the only thing you cared about were the valid arrangements of the moduli, there would be massively more solutions than your numbers suggest. (For instance, we can make some more "local" changes to your example by freely picking $2$ or $3$ for both $m_6$ and $m_{12}$. That already gives 4 arrangements even before the trick with swapping $7$ and $11$. If one starts meddling with the system in a more substantial way I'm sure the count be pushed much higher.)

Comment: Okay, @CarlOlimb maybe now I understand: what you're counting is not the valid arrangements, but the $x$ values that arise from valid arrangements? (This would make irrelevant the trick that I described in my last comment, for instance.)